# Field repository in ...NoteController required a bean of type ...NoteRepository that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I tried to execute a Spring project, but always returns an error, I don't know if the problem is the version of Spring Boot.

I have two projects:

- IntegrationCore (spring boot project);
- IntegrationModel (only for models);

The project IntegrationCore contains the references of project IntegrationModel (Build Path -> Projects)

When I execute the project IntegrationCore (Run as -> Spring boot app), returns a console error:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field repository in com.integration.controller.NoteController required a    > bean of type 'com.integration.repository.NoteRepository' that could not be  > found.
>   Action:
>   Consider defining a bean of type 'com.integration.repository.NoteRepository' > in your configuration.

I tried:

- change the version of Spring boot from 1.5.7 to 1.5.20;
- includes the anotation of mongoDb in Application class;
- insert anotations to references the IntegrationCore packages;

IntegrationCore

```
 src/
 ├── main/
 │   └── java/
 |       ├── com.integration/
 |       |   └── IntegrationCoreApplication.java
 |       ├── com.integration.controller/
 |       |   └── NoteController.java
 |       └── com.integration.repository/
 |           └── NoteRepository.java
```

IntegrationModel

```
 src/
 ├── main/
 │   └── java/
 |       ├── com.integrationModel/
 |       |   └── NoteStatuses.java
 |       └── com.integrationModel.filter/
 |           └── NoteStatusesParams.java
```

IntegrationCoreApplication.java

```
package com.integration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"com.integration", "com.integrationModel"})
public class IntegrationCoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IntegrationCoreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

NoteController.java

```
package com.integration.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.integrationModel.NoteStatuses;
import com.integrationModel.filter.NoteStatusesParams;
import com.integration.repository.NoteRepository;

@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/services/nota")
public class NoteController {

    @Autowired
    private NoteRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getStatuses", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<NoteStatuses> getStatuses(@RequestBody List<NoteStatusesParams> params) {
        return repository.findStatuses(params);
    }

}
```

NoteRepository.java

```
package com.integration.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.integrationModel.NoteStatuses;
import com.integrationModel.filter.NoteStatusesParams;

@Service
public interface NoteRepository {
    List<NoteStatuses> findStatuses(List<NoteStatusesParams> param);
}
```

NoteStatusesParams.java

```
package com.integrationModel.filter;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Singular;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class NoteStatusesParams {
    @Singular
    private List<String> orderNumbers;
    private String providerCpfCnpj;
    private String noteNumber;
}
```

NoteStatuses.java

```
package com.integrationModel;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import java.util.Date;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class NoteStatuses {

    private Boolean physicalReceipt;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your `NoteRepository` is an interface, but is has no implementations since you have not extended any `spring-data` repository interface nor provided any own implementation of this interface. You annotated your interface with `@Service` and that won't work.

Comment: Please change the subject to readable one "Field repository in … required a bean of type … that could not be found" is little complicated !

Comment: @michalk I tried without ```@Service```, but the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your following definition.

```
@Service
public interface NoteRepository {
    List<NoteStatuses> findStatuses(List<NoteStatusesParams> param);
}
```

It's an interface and you can not define this as a Service using @Service. Spring will try to create an instance for this bean and it is failing because of that.

You need to define this as a repository using `@Repostiry` annotation and by extending your relevant repository i.e JPA or ElasticSearch repository.

Comment: You need to also specify the repository package scanning. Also NoteStatuses is JPA entity or elastic document or mongo? what kind of repository you are trying to create

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I got this project and I believe it worked the way it is, but it has no documentation. How can I identify the type of repository I will need?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using NoteRepository as a Repository then it's better to use @Repository rather than @Service.**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class IntegrationCoreApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IntegrationCoreApplication.class, args);
    }
```

The **@SpringBootApplication** annotation is equivalent to using @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration, and @ComponentScan with their default attributes.
And the difference between using 3 annotations and 1 @SpringBootApplication is just that with these,

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({ ABC.class, XYZ.class })
```

@Component-annotated classes are not detected automatically and the user-defined beans are imported explicitly (see @Import).

Comment: Okay, I tested it with the ```@Repository``` annotation but I did not understand your suggestion in using the three annotations, would I have to add all the classes within that annotation ```@Import```?